# Unable to pass Facebook User properties to Firebase FIRAuth in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, firebase, fbsdkloginkit

I'm using the following function to login a User with a Facebook Token and the Firebase FIRAuth function. There is no error and no print of **email** property. As if the function wouldn't be called.

```
var login = FBSDKLoginManager()

@IBOutlet weak var fbBtnPressed: UIButton!

@IBAction func fbBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], from: self) { (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult, Error) in

        if Error != nil {
            print("The login with Facebook don't working. Erro: \(Error)")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
            print("Login with Facebook ok. \(accessToken)")                

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (email, error) in

                if (error != nil) {
                    print("The login in the Firebase broke \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Login in the Firebase ok \(email)")   
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }       
}
```

Comment: "does not work" is not really helpful.. DUDE! what is happening? what print will executed? what happens in the backend? what happens on the screen? what happens in the console? do you honestly expect help just by posting some code (that looks okay so far)?

Comment: @DavidSeek Gives no error showing friend. It's like if FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn just not execute

Comment: will: `print("Login with Facebook ok. \(accessToken)")` be executed?

Comment: will `print("Login in the Firebase ok \(email)")` be executed?

Comment: @DavidSeek just "accessToken" executed. it returns the value of the access key

Comment: so `print("Login with Facebook ok. \(accessToken)") ` this?

Comment: no print from `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (email, error) in` ?

Comment: Yes...the "error" and "email". It is as if never had entered the code line

Comment: please try a print statement without your `if / else error` like: `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
  print("test")
}`

Comment: to see if this line will get executed in the first place

Comment: @DavidSeek don't work, it is as if he stop the executing the line in print("Login with Facebook ok. \(accessToken)")

Comment: could you please execute the following code AFTER this login func to check if there is some user logged in in the background?

Comment: `if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
    print(user.displayName=

} else {
    print("no user signed in")
}`

Comment: @DavidSeek I test here, and showed "the user signed in" :(

Comment: well... then try to logout a user first before calling the FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn function

Comment: probably there is currently a user logged into your app and that's why is isn't working OR the auth is working but `email` is for some reason a void value and can't be used on this place

Comment: possible workout around to not have to logout would be to delete the app from your phone/simulator and reinstall. then the login func would be called for sure

Comment: @DavidSeek Thank you for your time. Unfortunately still the same way. I understand your point of view, but do not know why does not work.

Comment: and are you able to work with the logged in user? i mean. it would not be the worst case if the user is logged in at the back and just your print statements not called as long as the user will be logged in and you're able to use him

Comment: that way you could still work with your current user as here `if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser { print(user.displayName= } else { print("no user signed in") }`

Comment: bro. have a look at my answer. i'm almost sure that it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, it seems to be a change in Swift3 in combination with the Keychain swap.

You have to enable the Keychange Sharing in your project under capabilities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: my last option to help you would be if you could set up a simple test project with the same setup and send me a github link so i could check it out.

Comment: you will not believe, i added again the frameworks Bolts.framework, FBSDKCoreKit.framework and FBSDKLoginKit.framework, and simply worked